# Can you use a web application framework like react or vue as a templating engine?

Tags: javascript, .net, t4

I am shopping around for a web application framework (React, Vue, Angular, Aurelia, etc.) for the next generation of my web app (which currently uses the beloved but pretty moribund [Knockout](https://knockoutjs.com/) plus ASP.NET Razor views).

I am also shopping around for a replacement for [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022), because I'm having a lot of problems with them. (Hard to automate, poor editing model, poor tooling, only works in Visual Studio, etc.)

One of the main functions of a tool like Vue is to create an HTML page that is data-bound to a view model, making it very similar to text templating.

Is is possible to generalize this so that you could use Vue (or React, etc.) to generate *arbitrary* text, that is, not limited to HTML flavored markup, so that I can use the same tool for HTML generation that I use for generating all sorts of other things (like source code)?

Comment: It is possible, but my resident Vue expert says it's not ideal, because Vue expects to live on a web server of some sort.

Comment: Doesn't it normally run in the browser?

Comment: Of course, but it's served to the web browser first.  I don't know exactly why it's unsuitable as a templating engine, but I can get more specifics.  Also, my conversation with him centered on creating HTML reports, not code generation.

Comment: I'd really appreciate the wisdom. I really need a new templating tool, and I would really like it to be something that uses the same skills as the other stuff I do all day.

Comment: This is what I would reach for in lieu of T4 templates: https://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator

Comment: For your web application framework, I am familiar with all of the ones you mentioned.  We chose Vue because it doesn't have Angular's steep learning curve, it has two-way data binding unlike React, and we have in-house expertise in it.  It's a bit younger than the others but it has an incredible adoption curve right now due to its approachability, its very clean coding style, and its exceptional training and documentation.

Comment: In my evaluation, I am indeed preferring Vue to React, because of things like that, and the syntax in general. I believe Vue works more like knockout, which I love, and am only leaving because it just hasn't been updated in so long and there isn't much community using it anymore.

Comment: This looks very promising as a T4 replacement: https://github.com/jondot/hygen